# how to change default text color in ListView in flutter Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, listviewitem

I want to change the text color of the `ListView` with along with the Checkbox but can't change the text color dynamically with the `ListView's` onselected item?
I also add the color in the set State option but cant find the result I was lookin for.

here is my code:

```
ListView(
        children: [
          Text(
            '''   Categories''',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff181725),
              fontSize: 24,
              fontFamily: "Gilroy",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 13),
          ...checkBoxListOne.map(
            (item) => ListTile(
              onTap: () => onAllClicked(item),
              leading: Checkbox(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffC2C2C2),
                  width: 2,
                ),
                activeColor: Color(0xff53B175),
                value: item.value,
                onChanged: (value) => onAllClicked(item),
              ),
              title: Text(
                item.title!,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff181725),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          Text(
            '''   Brand''',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff181725),
              fontSize: 24,
              fontFamily: "Gilroy",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 13),
          ...checkBoxListTwo.map(
            (item) => ListTile(
              onTap: () => onAllClicked(item),
              leading: Checkbox(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffC2C2C2),
                  width: 2,
                ),
                activeColor: Color(0xff53B175),
                value: item.value,
                onChanged: (value) => onAllClicked(item),
              ),
              title: Text(item.title!),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

and here is the `setState` part :

`onAllClicked(CheckBoxModal ckbItem) { setState(() { ColoredBox( color: Color(0xff53B175), ); ckbItem.value = !ckbItem.value; }); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a field `isSelected` to the `item` objects in your `checkBoxListOne` list, and set/reset that field in the `onTap` of the item (`item.isSelected = !item.isSelected`), then call `setState(){}`.  When you render the `item`, instead of `activeColor: Color(0xff53B175)` do something like `activeColor: item.isSelected ? Color(0xff53B175) : Color(0xffffffff)`.

As a result of this change, the list is re-rendered whenever an item is tapped, and the color of the item when rendered is dependent on its 'tapped or not' state.

If you cannot (or don't want to) add a field, you can create a separate `bool` array of the same length as your `checkBoxListOne` list and use that to keep track of which item is selected.

Comment: I changed all as you said but there's a error said `A nullable expression can't be used as a condition. Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition. `  Code: 
`CheckBoxModal(isSelected: false),` &
`class CheckBoxModal {
  bool value;
  bool? isSelected;
  CheckBoxModal({
    this.value = false,
    this.isSelected ,
  });
}`
and 
`onAllClicked(CheckBoxModal ckbItem) {
    setState(() {
      ColoredBox(
        color: Color(0xff53B175),
      );
      ckbItem.value = !ckbItem.value;
      ckbItem.isSelected = !ckbItem.isSelected;
    });
  }`

Comment: The isSelected field must be bool, not bool?